# Getting "User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp" for a non user object save

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is super weird. This started happening last night, went away this morning and now it's back again. I am trying to save a Follow object with the current user as the Follower and anther user as Following. The code is:

```
let follow = PFObject(className: "Follow")
follow["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()
follow["following"] = ["__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": objectId]       
follow.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The error is being caused by the second line where I'm setting the current user as the follower. If I comment out that line then the Follow is saved in the database without a follower just fine. But with the line, it throws this error.

I have no clue what could be causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you logging in with the other user during your testing? I've seen this error if I change users via login/logout and the referenced object is another user who has a dirty key (i.e., new data that needs to be saved).

One quick fix may be to try creating a pointer for the current user in a similar way that you're doing it for the other user:

```
let follow = PFObject(className: "Follow")
follow["follower"] = ["__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": PFUser.currentUser().objectId]       
follow["following"] = ["__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": objectId]       
follow.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I came to a similar conclusion and cleared out my database. Deleted all the installations from my test devices and started from scratch. So far I havent seen the error. I was gonna wait for a bit longer to see if the error returns and if not then post it as an answer.

Comment: does anyone have an objective C version of this answer ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend always checking if currentUser exists or not. This check is straight forward from Parse documentation:

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
if currentUser != nil {
  follow["follower"] = currentUser
} else {
  print("error")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I have check for that just before this code and the Current User is definitely there.  Its odd because the error is about saving the user whereas I am not saving the user. I'm just using the user as a reference.

Comment: @GgnDpSingh you say in your original post: where I'm setting the current user as the follower. You actually doing the opposite...that is setting the follower to current user.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you.I am setting the user as a 'Pointer' in the Follow Object. I am not making a change to the Current User object itself.